# How to manage port forwarding rules in a centralized way

Tags: networking, macos, port-forwarding

What is the best practice to maintain port forwarding rules for a group of users using macOS in centralized way (configuration files with rules is sufficient)?

Let's say, I would like to redirect certain http traffic using patterns within localhost:

```
localhost:8080/test/** -> localhost:9090/test/**
localhost:8080/blabla -> localhost:9090/blabla
```

How to do that (is there any tool for it?) and how to maintain that (looking for best practices)?

Comment: What is this for? (And, is it actually localhost->localhost, or is it really something else?) This doesn't seem like the kind of thing that would _have_ "best practices", to be honest.

Comment: What are you currently using to set the rules? I've seen `ipfw` rules, or various SSH stuff like manual `ssh -L` tunnels, or `LocalForward` entries in ssh_config for example. In most cases, you could be adjusting the binding config of the listening app instead, and centralize that

Comment: Best practice for localhost → locahost is "allow everything"